# How Can I Perform ALT + > in Iterm2

Tags: bash, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, iterm2

In a standard bash shell one can go backwards through the history by hitting the `UP` key, and forwards by hitting the `DOWN` key.  If you've hit up a bunch and want to get back to the start you can hit `ALT + >`.

However in Iterm2 if you hit those keys you get "�", and it has no effect on your bash history.  Is there any way to send `ALT + >` in Iterm2, so that if I just hit `UP` 50 times I can get back to where I was without having to hit `DOWN` 50 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix with <kbd>Esc</kbd>, either by hand or you can configure it to use one of the option keys for this:

[image: Screenshot of preferences.]

Image source: [Setting up Mac OS X and iTerm2 for Emacs](http://azaleasays.com/2013/07/05/setting-up-mac-os-x-and-iterm2-for-emacs),
which has some other tips.

You can also get a fresh prompt by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in bash.